# Remove disabled scrollbars from fancybox iframe popup

Tags: html, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

We've implemented fancybox iframe popups throughout our system and it works great, but I've noticed these annoying horizontal scrollbars popping out on the outside of the frame. We get scrollbars where necesary inside our content area, but these ones just show up 100% of the time even when there's nothing to scroll. I've tried a number of things with CSS but have not had any luck thus far. Screenshot below to show what I'm referring to.

Any ideas?

https://ibb.co/88ZhBbX

EDIT: https://ibb.co/82bPxkd - image showing overflow being set to hidden on iframe and wrapper container.

Comment: overflow-y: hidden; didn't do the trick? What have you tried?  I would help but, it's difficult to troubleshoot since you haven't posted any code.

Comment: @A.J.Nock thanks for your reply. Yeah I've tried setting overflow hidden on both the iframe and its parent container. See 2nd screenshot in post description showing the iframe being highlighted in dev tools and overflow-y being set. You can also see inline that the parent has it set as well. I've also tried setting just the entire overflow to hidden but neither seem to control it. I'm not sure if something within the JS library is placing that on the screen?